# Cannot read value using @Value() in application.yml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml, environment-variables

I am simply trying to set default values for environment variables as shown below:

```
app:
  security:
    testUser: ${TEST_USER:spring}
    testPassword: ${TEST_PASSWORD:secret}
```

I am trying to read this values:

```
@Value("${TEST_USER}")
private String testUser;

@Value("${TEST_PASSWORD}")
private String testPassword;
```

However, when running app, it does not read the default values and throws error:

> Could not resolve placeholder 'TEST_USER' in value "${TEST_USER}"

I also tried as:

```
testUser: ${TEST_USER:#{spring}}
```

But still the same error. So, how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to say `@Value("${app.security.testUser}")`. It will take the value from TEST_USER environment variable or default to **spring** if such an environment variable does not exist